# Sometimes Getting IndexOutOfBound while accesing menu item in Android

Tags: android

I have a menu -

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="com.example.ju_group.health_assist.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
        android:title="Help"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/disable"
        android:checkableBehavior="all"
        android:visible="true">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/dis_new"
            android:title="Disable PopUp"
            android:visible="true"/>

    </group>
</menu>
```

So I am accessing the item `dis_new` in-

```
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    if(disable_popup==1)
        menu.getItem(R.id.dis_new).setChecked(true); //here I'm getting error
        return true;  //we have inflated the menu
    }
```

`disable_popup` is earlier set to 1 or 0, depending on certain conditions.
Now I am getting an IndexOutOfBound Exception when I set the item checked.
But many times it's getting executed correctly(with both `disable_popup` values 0 and 1).

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2131624239, size is 2
```

is the exception message.

I used try-catch to contain the error and taken appropriate steps, but I want to know what is causing the error.

EDIT:  stacktrace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.*******, PID: 829
  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2131624239, size is 2
 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
 at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.getItem(MenuBuilder.java:741)
 at com.example.*****.SymptomsAnalyze.onCreateOptionsMenu(SymptomsAnalyze.java:113)
 at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:362)
 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:98)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:335)
 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:98)
 at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:454)
 at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire stacktrace please ?

Comment: To get a menu item by its ID, use `findItem()` instead. `getItem()` retrieves by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method menu.getItem(int) is for accessing menu item by its index(for example: 0, 1, 2). If you want to access menu item by id, you should use [menu.findItem(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem(int)).

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    if(disable_popup==1)
         menu.findItem(R.id.dis_new).setChecked(true); //findItem() instead of getItem()

    return true;  //we have inflated the menu
}
```

Comment: thanks, but can u explain why it was working correctly sometimes?

Comment: I have no idea how it could work correctly. :(

Answer (score 2):

the getItem is expecting a position, not an id change this line

```
  menu.getItem(R.id.dis_new) to this menu.getItem(1)
```

Comment: sometimes it returns index execption